# What is the data storage cost for 10GB of data in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the data storage cost for 10GB of data?

​

I​ see the price per TB but is that also the minimum per month.

Are there any lower tiers for personal use or learning Snowflake? ​
I am aware of the 400 DBU credit for the first 30 days.

I am more curious about the costs after the first 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question.  For the best answer to your question, I'd run this past your Account Manager as they would be able to address TOTAL COST most appropriately in terms of both Storage AND Compute.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am asking about a personal account and thus do not have an Account Manager.

Comment: Hi Pranav - Fair enough... I'd recommend emailing our Sales Team at "sales @snowflake.com" to tackle this question as there may be some variables that require more of a discussion around the total use of your Snowflake instance.